# spark RDD pipe to sed escaping characters

Tags: scala, sed, apache-spark

I have a using the pipe function in spark RDD like this:

```
val custPrdRep = custPrdGrp.
pipe("sed s/CompactBuffer//g").
pipe("sed 's/\\], \\[//g'")
```

everything works except for the last pipe function...

I dont' get any results back when doing

```
custPrdRep.collect
```

in shell, this does work though:

```
$ echo "], [a" | sed  's/\\], \\[//g'
a
```

If I try it this way,

```
pipe("sed 's/\], \[//g'")
```

I get this error:

```
scala> val custPrdRep = custPrdGrp.pipe("sed s/CompactBuffer//g").pipe("sed s/|,/|/g").pipe("sed 's/\], \[//g'")
<console>:1: error: invalid escape character
       val custPrdRep = custPrdGrp.pipe("sed s/CompactBuffer//g").pipe("sed s/|,/|/g").pipe("sed 's/\], \[//g'")
                                                                                                     ^
<console>:1: error: invalid escape character
       val custPrdRep = custPrdGrp.pipe("sed s/CompactBuffer//g").pipe("sed s/|,/|/g").pipe("sed 's/\], \[//g'")
```

am I escaping the right characters in the right way?

Comment: Why do you need `pipe` in the first place? If I remember your previous question you can simply create an output string in Scala without even touching regular expressions.

Comment: Something like `custPrdGrp.map{case (k, vals) => {val valsString = vals.mkString(", "); s"{$k:, {$valsString}}" }}` or whatever format you wanted.

Comment: @zero323 that works great! Can you also use that to format each element in value pair...so if I had this `val custPrd = accts.map(a => (a(0), ((a(1)), (a(2), a(3), a(4), a(5), a(6), a(7), a(8)))))`, can a(2), a(3), etc... different?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand desired output but I am pretty sure you can. If you provide an example input (something that can be simply copied and pasted) and expected output I'll  be happy to help, but I think it deserves a separate question.

Comment: @zero323...thanks, I asked a related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095742/format-a-k-v-w-pair-in-spark-rdd ...can you post your response as the answer as well....

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
val custPrdRep = custPrdGrp.pipe("sed s/CompactBuffer//g").pipe("sed s/|,/|/g").pipe("sed 's/\\], \\[//g'")
```

(note the additional `\` before `[` and `]`)

Also, I don't know which shell you're using, but in bash:

```
echo "], [a" | sed  's/\\], \\[//g'
```

will not work.

```
echo "], [a" | sed  "s/\\], \\[//g"
```

will

Comment: I tried doing `pipe("sed 's/\\], \\[//g'")` but still got nothing back....I think I'm already trying to do it that way though...

Comment: `sed` part looks OK, and it works just fine with PySpark but there is still something wrong on Scala part.  BTW You can use raw strings (raw"""foo""") to avoid escaping,