# formatting a nested map in a map in Spark rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
1007|CNSMR_CARD|1|1|1|1|1|1|1
1007|CNSMR_LOCL_IM_CHKG|1|1|1|1|1|1|1
1009|CNSMR_DIRCT_CHKG|4|4|4|4|4|1|1
1009|CNSMR_DIRCT_OTHR|4|4|4|4|4|1|1
1009|CNSMR_DIRCT_SAVG|4|4|4|4|4|1|1
1009|CNSMR_LOCL_IM_CHKG|4|4|4|4|4|1|1
1010|CNSMR_LOCL_IM_CHKG|1|1|1|1|1|1|1
1012|CNSMR_LOCL_IM_CHKG|1|1|1|1|1|1|1
1033|CNSMR_DIRCT_CHKG|1|1|1|1|2|1|1
```

Then create an rdd like this:

```
val custFile = sc.textFile("custInfo.txt").map(line => line.split('|'))

val custPrd = custFile.map(a => (a(0), ((a(1)), Map("PRVCY_MAIL: " -> a(2), "PRVCY_CALL: " -> a(3), "PRVCY_SWP: " -> a(4), "PRVCY_FCRA: " -> a(5), "PRVCY_GLBA: " -> a(6), "PRVCY_PIPE: " -> a(7), "PRVCY_AFIL: " -> a(8)))))

val custGrp = custPrd.groupByKey

val custPrdGrp = custGrp.map{case (k, vals) => {val valsString = vals.mkString(", "); s"'$k' | {$valsString}" }}
```

which gives me back this results:

```
res4: Array[String] = Array(
'106' | {(CNSMR_LOCL_IM_CHKG,Map(PRVCY_MAIL:  -> 4, PRVCY_GLBA:  -> 4, PRVCY_FCRA:  -> 4, PRVCY_AFIL:  -> 1, PRVCY_PIPE:  -> 1, PRVCY_CALL:  -> 4, PRVCY_SWP:  -> 4))}, 
'107' | {(CNSMR_DIRCT_CHKG,Map(PRVCY_MAIL:  -> 1, PRVCY_GLBA:  -> 1, PRVCY_FCRA:  -> 1, PRVCY_AFIL:  -> 1, PRVCY_PIPE:  -> 1, PRVCY_CALL:  -> 4, PRVCY_SWP:  -> 1)), (CNSMR_DIRCT_SAVG,Map(PRVCY_MAIL:  -> 1, PRVCY_GLBA:  -> 1, PRVCY_FCRA:  -> 1, PRVCY_AFIL:  -> 1, PRVCY_PIPE:  -> 1, PRVCY_CALL:  -> 4, PRVCY_SWP:  -> 1))}
```

but what I want an array like this:

```
'106' | {'CNSMR_LOCL_IM_CHKG': {PRVCY_MAIL: 4, PRVCY_GLBA: 4, PRVCY_FCRA: 4, PRVCY_AFIL: 1, PRVCY_PIPE: 1, PRVCY_CALL: 4, PRVCY_SWP: 4}}
'107' | {'CNSMR_DIRCT_CHKG': {PRVCY_MAIL: 1, PRVCY_GLBA: 1, PRVCY_FCRA: 1, PRVCY_AFIL: 1, PRVCY_PIPE: 1, PRVCY_CALL: 4, PRVCY_SWP: 1}}, {'CNSMR_DIRCT_SAVG': {PRVCY_MAIL: 1, PRVCY_GLBA: 1, PRVCY_FCRA: 1, PRVCY_AFIL: 1, PRVCY_PIPE: 1, PRVCY_CALL: 4, PRVCY_SWP: 1}}
```

to format the second map, I tried something like this but got an error:

```
    val custPrdGrp = custGrp.map{case (k, vals) => {val valsString = vals map { case (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7) => {val sets = vals.mkString(", "); s"$val1, $val2, $val3, $val4, $val5, $val6, $val7"}}.mkString(", "); s"'$k' | {$valsString}" }}

<console>:27: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: ?
       val custPrdGrp = custGrp.map{case (k, vals) => {val valsString = vals map { case (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7) => {val sets = vals.mkString(", "); s"$val1, $val2, $val3, $val4, $val5, $val6, $val7"}}.mkString(", "); s"'$k' | {$valsString}" }}
                                                                                 ^
```

How do you format a nested map in a map in Spark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with simple `Map[String, String]`

```
val m: Map[String,String] = Map(
   "PRVCY_MAIL" -> "1", "PRVCY_GLBA" -> "1",
   "PRVCY_FCRA" -> "1", "PRVCY_AFIL" -> "1",
   "PRVCY_PIPE" -> "1", "PRVCY_CALL" -> "1",
   "PRVCY_SWP" -> "1"
)
```

Note that I dropped formatting elements like `:` and whitscapes. It is not required buy in my opinion much cleaner.

Now we can define two small helper:

```
def formatMap(sep: String = ": ",
    left: String = "{", right: String = "}")(m: Map[String, String]) = {
  val items = m.toSeq.map{case (k, v) => s"$k$sep$v"}.mkString(", ")
  s"$left$items$right"
}
```

Lets check how it works

```
scala> formatMap()(m)
res50: String = {PRVCY_CALL: 1, PRVCY_SWP: 1, PRVCY_MAIL: 1, PRVCY_AFIL: 1, PRVCY_FCRA: 1, PRVCY_PIPE: 1, PRVCY_GLBA: 1}

scala> formatMap(sep="=")(m)
res51: String = {PRVCY_CALL=1, PRVCY_SWP=1, PRVCY_MAIL=1, PRVCY_AFIL=1, PRVCY_FCRA=1, PRVCY_PIPE=1, PRVCY_GLBA=1}

scala> formatMap(sep="|", left="[", right="]")(m)
res52: String = [PRVCY_CALL|1, PRVCY_SWP|1, PRVCY_MAIL|1, PRVCY_AFIL|1, PRVCY_FCRA|1, PRVCY_PIPE|1, PRVCY_GLBA|1]
```

Now lets clean up what you already have. First lets extract names:

```
val keys = Array(
   "PRVCY_MAIL", "PRVCY_CALL", "PRVCY_SWP", "PRVCY_FCRA",
   "PRVCY_GLBA", "PRVCY_PIPE", "PRVCY_AFIL"
)
```

Rewrite map:

```
val custPrd = custFile.map(a => (a(0), (a(1), keys.zip(a.drop(2)).toMap)))
```

Group as before

```
val custGrp = custPrd.groupByKey
```

And map

```
val custPrdGrp = custGrp.map{case (k, vals) => {
  val valsString = vals.map{case (id, m) => {
    val fmtM = formatMap()(m)
    s"'$id': $fmtM"
  }}.mkString(", ")
  s"'$k' | {$valsString}"
}}
```

Quick check:

```
scala> custPrdGrp.first
res56: String = '1012' | {'CNSMR_LOCL_IM_CHKG': {PRVCY_CALL: 1, PRVCY_SWP: 1, PRVCY_MAIL: 1, PRVCY_AFIL: 1, PRVCY_FCRA: 1, PRVCY_PIPE: 1, PRVCY_GLBA: 1}}
```

You should probably extract anonymous function used above in a similar way I've done for `formatMap` but I'll leave it as an exercise for you.